# How to look at position of debugging error in vba?

Tags: vba, debugging

when I was running vba code, it appeared the warning like picture below. In some case it's not highlight the debugging position. With so many code lines, have to spend many time to check. So how's way to check the position of debugging with the warning.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmBDz.png)

Comment: That looks like a `Msgbox`, do you have `On Error Goto ____` (where ____ can be anything) anywhere in your code?

Comment: In VBE, looks for `Tools` > `Options...` then in Options window, go to `General` tab and under `Error Trapping`, change to `Break on All Errors` and run the code, the error prompt will now allow you to debug and shows you which line did it occur. You have to remember to change Error Trapping back to other 2 options after debugging though.

Comment: @RaymondWu but I don't know where the compile error occur to add "On Error Goto" instruction

Comment: Try what I said in my 2nd comment and run the code, you should now get the actual error prompt that allows you to debug.